# ITEXT 7 - Doument Add method throws exception while on adding Paragraph object in .Net Core

Tags: .net, pdf, .net-core, itext, itext7

I tried to generate a simple PDF using ITEXT 7 package. I just copy the source code from the documentation page and tried to run the .Net Core Console Application. It throws an exception. I'm not sure what I missed. I tried a lot to fix the issue but failed.

**Package Info:**
Name: *itext7*
Version: *7.1.16*

**Exception Message:**

> Ex Message    **"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."   string**

**ITEXT Documentation:**
https://itextpdf.com/en/products/itext-7/itext-7-core

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(new FileStream("G:/hello.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)));
        Document document = new Document(pdfDocument, iText.Kernel.Geom.PageSize.A4);

        String line = "Hello! Welcome to iTextPdf";
        var para = new Paragraph(line);

        document.Add(new Paragraph(line));

        document.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Awesome PDF just got created.");
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, something's wrong with the dependencies/fonts, so definitely not a problem with code but rather something with the project set up. Can you attach your project file please?

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late, but anyhow.

This is a known iText problem, and you can find a solution in this thread: [Null Reference Exception when calling iText7 PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm() in .Net Core 3.1 class library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64147520/null-reference-exception-when-calling-itext7-pdfacroform-getacroform-in-net-c)